# Swagger examples for multilevel objects will not showup

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm trying to show custom example just for 401 Response status code (overriding default example values) But the following code will not do this for some reason (default values stay in place) Status.Code and Status.Verbal will not set, also the "Agent" object will notgo into Content.

```
paths:
  /api/Users/Login:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/LoginCredentials'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Login OK / Agent Object
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/RestResponse'
              example:
                Content:
                  schema:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Agent'
        '401':
          description: Incorrect credentials
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/RestResponse'
              example:
                Status:
                  Verbal: Error
                  Code: 1074
                Content: null


components:
  schemas:
    Agent:
      type: object

    RestResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        Status:
          type: object
          properties:
            Verbal:
              type: string
              example: Success
            Code:
              type: string
              format: int32
              example: 104
        Content:
          type: object
        Exception:
          type: object

    LoginCredentials:
      type: object
      required:
        - UserName
        - Password
      properties:
        UserName:
          type: string
          format: email
          example: user@not.net
        Password:
          type: string
          example: password
```

What I expect to see as response examples:
200:

```
{
  "Status": {
    "Verbal": "Success",
    "Code": 104
  },
  "Content": "Agent{}"
}
```

401:

```
{
  "Status": {
    "Verbal": "Error",
    "Code": 1074
  },
  "Content": null
}
```

Comment: The 401 example works fine for me in the latest Swagger Editor / Swagger UI https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn2VZ.png.

Comment: It's not quite right, I expect it to return RestResponse{Status{"Verbal": "Error" "Code": 1074
}} object

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Could you please edit your post and add the full JSON you expect to see in Swagger UI?

Comment: @Helen I Updated the question to show my expectation outputs. I'm not sure if i should use schema for the examples at all or use components.examples